# Library, control for C# that represents table in Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, controls, tabular

I need to put a table (like spreadsheet but without formulas, only numbers) in a Form. It would be nice if it had adjustable size. Do you know any control like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about DataGridView?

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx)

Comment: I have following question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459899/how-to-relate-double-to-datagridview